# Tableau Workbook No Longer Displaying Data

Tags: tableau-api

I saved a Tableau workbook on Nov 2015. Now when I open it, none of the maps or graphs appear in any of the tabs.

However if I hover over the tab, it shows thumb-file of the graphic, i.e.

Please tell me how to repair this. Else it will take lot of resources to re-create tableau workbook again. Thanks!

[image]

Worksheet is already auto-updated

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking Worksheet/Auto update/ Auto Update worksheet?  A version of tableau a while back disabled this by default when I upgraded.

Comment: @CharlieHaley Yes, these features were already enabled. I updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the data source from the workbook and reconnecting it? Is it possible the data source got corrupted? Is it possible the data source got moved/changed?

Comment: Edit the data source -- i.e. double click the word incidents in the top left under the word Data. Then look at the data.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I will check this

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I think the file was damaged. I copied over the data to new EXCEL, gave it the old name, and now it works fine. Thanks!